# Foreign Key Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have the following models:

```
class status(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #data
class next(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sender')
    target = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='target')
    #data
class settings(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        #data
```

and want to Query next and status with the following output: next,nextdata,status(target)

=> Attach the status of the target to the (next) queryset

Is this possible via Django Query? Or should I just write raw SQL

#

Edit:
Sender in this Query is always current.user,
and every User has exactly 1 status

#

cheers,
keslol

Comment: Problem is that the way you model it, there can be *multiple* `next`s for both the same `sender` and the same `target`. So there is no "one" next, there can be zero, one or more if you want. Usually it is bet to model it more properly.

Comment: For each User there is ALWAYS 1 status, + next=current.user . So I only need to line up status(target)

Comment: Then I think it makes more sense to make a `ForeignKey` in `status` or in `User` that refers to the next one, since that modeling makes it *impossible* to make multiple links, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab the status data through a select_related or values grab if you are querying the "next" model. You probably should add a related_name param to user on your status model. Here's two ways (after you add the related_name as status):

**Select related**

```
for next_instance in next.objects.filter(...).select_related('target__status'):
    # next_instance data is accessible directly through instance attributes
    next_instance.id
    # Because we select_related status, no extra query is done to grab the data for target
    # or status
    next_instance.target.status.id
```

As a small note, *select_related* is used here instead of *prefetch_related* as we are traversing FROM many TO 1. If we were coming FROM User TO next (1 to many), we would have to use *prefetch_related*, and we would not be able to guarantee only one result.

**Values**

```
data = next.objects.filter(...).values(
    # fields you want as string arguments
    'id',
    'target__status__id'
)
# Data will be a Queryset that if you iterate through will be iterating through 
# dictionaries that contain key value pairs for the fields you put in values.
```

Further Reading:

Here is the Queryset documentation for select_related:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Here is the Queryset documentation for values:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#values

Comment: Perfect, {{obj.target.status.fe}  to access the value in a template after.